# How can i render image from assets folder in vue?

Tags: vue.js

I’m having a problem with rendering image that is in assets folder in my vue js project.I’m creating card object where one filed is the string containig source of the image,then when i try to pass that field in template as  i’m getting an error 404 image not found.

I tried to pass the url from random image i found on google and it works but won’t work with image from my assets folder.
I also double check path for misspelling but everything is ok.

Comment: you have use vite?

Comment: @TachibanaShin yes i’m using vite dev  server

Comment: https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#static-asset-handling or use `<img src="/src/assets/..." />`. in quasar please add `<img src="~assets/..` />`

Comment: @TachibanaShin thanks a lot,i managed to solve this with “import”

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the root of you project folder with the `@` symbol like this:

```
<img src="@/assets/images/home.png"/>
```

If your source is defined in a property, you need to use Vues `v-bind:src`:

```
<img v-bind:src="source" />
```